# Meaning of ごきけんになるわけだ

Tags: grammar, honorifics

The narrator explains his way of talking to adults, and then:

> するとそのおとなは、自分と同じように趣味のいい人間と知り合えたと感じて、ごきけんになるわけだ....
>   And that adult feels that he has been able to get to know a person with good hobbies like his own, and ????

I can't understand the last part (ごきけんになるわけだ).

Firstly, I assume the adult wouldn't put ご on a word referring to himself so I guess ごきけん is the narrator. So maybe I can translate it as:

> surely he (the narrator) will become a distinguished person.

But I'm doubtful. Isn't it a bit self-serving for the narrator to assume that adult would add the honorific ご? These things confuse me a lot. Maybe my translation isn't even close. I have no confidence about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「するとそのおとなは、自分{じぶん}と同{おな}じように趣味{しゅみ}のいい人間{にんげん}と知{し}り合{あ}えたと感{かん}じて、[ごきけん]*になるわけだ。」

First, the word should be 「ごき**げ**ん」 and not 「ごき**け**ん」.  In kanji, it is 「ご機嫌{きげん}」.

> Firstly, I assume the adult wouldn't put ご on a word referring to himself so I guess ごきけん is the narrator.

Sorry but you look very confused here.  Or is it just several typos on your part?  I honestly have no idea what you are talking about.

**It is the adult that is "becoming happy" (= ごきげんになる) in the narrator/speaker's assumption**.

The core of this sentence is 「するとそのおとなはごきげんになるわけだ。」.  The middle part 「自分と同じように趣味のいい人間と知り合えたと感じて」　simply provides the reason  for そのおとな to become ごきげん.

**「自分」 here refers to 「そのおとな」**.

「趣味のいい人間」 refers directly and originally to the narrator, but also indirectly and secondarily refers to the adult because the adult thinks that he , too, has good taste.

The sentence, therefore, could be rewritten as:

> 「すると、自分と同じように趣味のいい人間と知り合えたと感じて、そのおとなはごきげんになるわけだ。」

My own mostly literal TL:

> "Then, upon feeling that he has been able to meet a man of good taste just as himself, the adult gets to become really happy."

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the context, I believe the original text is "**ごきげん**" with a **げ** rather than **け**, and the most fitting translation is "**... gets into a good mood**", which would make perfect sense as something that would happen when someone meets someone else with a good taste of hobbies.

This would also answer your second question -- It's **his/her** (the adult, not the narrator) mood, hence the **ご**. The narrator is being polite when talking about the adult.